# Should I know the webservice platform to generate Java classes from WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, soap, intellij-idea, wsdl

I have been given a wsdl endpoint and I am supposed develop a Java API to access the web service via SOAP. As for now I have managed to generate required Java classes from the WSDL. I am using IntelliJ Idea 13 and using it's webservices dialog to generate the classes. And there I am supposed to give the target platform which I don't know.

My problem is is it essential for me to know the platform in order to generate the classes properly or I can go with any platform there.